# AOT compilation of an Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I find it very challenging to find in the documentation any help on this important issue.. Indeed, after creating an estimator (canned or custom), one wants to `tf.compile` the resulting predictor, produce the `.so` and link it to one's project..

So I have my calib class in which I define a simple linear estimator

```
self.model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
        feature_columns=self.feature_columns,
        model_dir = self.model_dir)
```

After training, I want to 
1- get the trained model with optimal parameters (load it in my variable self.model)

2- extract the graph and freeze it

3- tf.compile that graph

I could not find any way to do parts 1- and 2-. Once I have them, part 3 is solved by using tf.compile

Can you please point me to a good way to it?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://medium.com/google-cloud/optimizing-tensorflow-models-for-serving-959080e9ddbf) helped a lot. It may help anyone passing by here